# I am beginner in c++, i want to know the error in my code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    cout << "entre two numbers";
    double x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;

    if (x != y)
        if (x % 2 == 0)
            if (y % 2 == 0)
                cout << "the two numbers are accepted";
            else
                cout << "the two numbers are not accepted";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [The error is exactly what the compiler tells you.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb6fc97a99fe134e). Any additional information you need about that?

Comment: You probably mean `int` instead of `double` if you're doing modulo operations.

Comment: i put int instead of double and the program runs but i do not know why double is wrong

Comment: Because % is not valid for doubles. You can use this instead: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)

Comment: do you mean that when i do modulo operations i must use int ?

Comment: ok than you so much

Comment: The duplicate discusses this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the variables of 'int' type instead of double and your error will get resolved.

Write below line.
int x,y;